# runbook Start-AzureRMVM works but never ends

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I have strange problem, while doing tutorials for starting VM from automation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual

My code is exactly like in first step, and it authenticates corretly:

```
workflow MyFirstRunbook-Workflow
    {
    $Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
    Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
    Start-AzureRmVM -Name 'VMName' -ResourceGroupName 'ResourceGroupName'
    }
```

Even when I check, VM starts,  but runbook never ends. It just says: "Running...." (more dots are appending all the time).
Any idea why is this happening? As it clearly works, but for some reason cannot end. And I think all settings are like in tutorial...
It is Powershell Workflow runbook.

Comment: In my lab, it works fine, where can you find the status is running? Have you try flush the browser or reload it? Could you please post the screenshot here?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Button start is not active and button stop is active. Here is screenshot ( I tried to publish and also changed code so I could see more, but nothing changes...): [link](http://imgur.com/a/6HjkM)
I have tried flushing browser and reloading :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To troubleshoot this issue more efficiently, we should do some test.
1.Use PowerShell to get the job **status**, script like this:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Login-AzureRmAccount
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-AzureRmAutomationJob -Id '29caa9f3-1862-4710-b1d3-c98c1841966f' -ResourceGroupName 'vm' -AutomationAccountName 'jasonrunbook' | select status

Status
------
Completed
```

2.Please test this PowerShell workflow runbook:

```
workflow jasontest2
{

    $Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
    Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
    $a = get-azurermvm -Name 'vmname' -ResourceGroupName 'rg'
    write-output $a
    Start-AzureRmVM -Name 'vmname' -ResourceGroupName 'rg'
    write-output "ok"

}
```

Then find the result in Output, if it still show running, please post the screenshot here.

Comment: 1. Status is running all the time
2. Using your script displays all VM information, and VM starts, but no "ok" displayed, and status checked in powershell is running.

Strange thing is that i found that 2 jobs managed to finish, one in 4 min, other in 10min (pretty long for such simple task), but all others needed to be stopped by me (after longer time). You can see it here: [link](http://imgur.com/a/QmADI) 
So that is even more strange that it finishes sometimes but mostly wont...

Comment: @shimon893 could you please try to use powershell to start your VM? how many time will take? it seems start this VM takes a long time.

Comment: It takes few minutes to start, but then powershell is still at exectution (no prompt, or results), but in portal I see that VM is running, I can log into VM, and work there, but powershell is hanging at this Start-AzureRmVM... I will try with different VM, but what could be reason of that VM to not return that it is already on?

Comment: @shimon893 ok, please try another VM to test it. please run this command to show the VM's status `get-azurermvm -Name vmname -ResourceGroupName rg -Status`. About the reason of that VM tot return the right status, I think we should ask another question to get more helps.  By the way, if my answer is helpful, please accept it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited. thanks:)

Comment: I have createn new VM and it works fine. Thanks for help, I was looking for reason in wrong place. Will try to work out problem with that VM, or just switch to new one. Thanks!

Comment: And the problem with Vm is that there is status: ProvisioningState/updating
Which is because of VHD (as i see in internet problem could occur when using account that have premium disk suport while using non-premium disks) - there is "updating" dialog in portal.

Comment: @shimon893 thank you for share the information, I will do some search about this issue:)

Comment: I am getting same issue - Start-AzureRMVM run from powershell command line hangs, can't ctrl+c/z/x/escape/break/whatever, VM has started.  At present I'm having issue that VM agent has disappeared from the VM wonder if connected?